# How to cut first n and last n columns?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I cut off the first *n* and the last *n* columns from a tab delimited file?

I tried this to cut first *n* column. But I have no idea to combine first and last n column

```
cut -f 1-10 -d "<CTR>v <TAB>" filename
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Cut can take several ranges in `-f`:

Columns up to 4 and from 7 onwards:

```
cut -f -4,7-
```

or for fields 1,2,5,6 and from 10 onwards:

```
cut -f 1,2,5,6,10-
```

etc

Comment: It works much better with a delimiter .......               cut -d ' ' -f -2 <<<'This is a test'

Comment: The default delimiter is tab, so @Yogamurthy's comment is the way to go.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "last n columns" part of the question.

Answer (score 9):

The first part of your question is easy. As already pointed out, cut accepts omission of either the starting or the ending index of a column range, interpreting this as meaning either “from the start to column *n* (inclusive)” or “from column *n* (inclusive) to the end,” respectively:

```
$ printf 'this:is:a:test' | cut -d: -f-2
this:is
$ printf 'this:is:a:test' | cut -d: -f3-
a:test
```

It also supports *combining* ranges. If you want, e.g., the first 3 and the last 2 columns in a row of 7 columns:

```
$ printf 'foo:bar:baz:qux:quz:quux:quuz' | cut -d: -f-3,6-
foo:bar:baz:quux:quuz
```

**However,** the second part of your question can be a bit trickier depending on what kind of input you’re expecting. If by “last *n* columns” you mean “last *n* columns (regardless of their indices in the overall row)” (i.e. because you don’t necessarily know how many columns you’re going to find in advance) then sadly this is not possible to accomplish using `cut` alone. In order to effectively use `cut` to pull out “the last *n* columns” in each line, the *total number* of columns present in each line must be known beforehand, ***and*** each line must be consistent in the number of columns it contains.

If you do *not* know how many “columns” may be present in each line (e.g. because you’re working with input that is not strictly tabular), then you’ll have to use something like `awk` instead. E.g., to use `awk` to pull out the last 2 “columns” (awk calls them *fields,* the number of which can vary per line) from each line of input:

```
$ printf '/a\n/a/b\n/a/b/c\n/a/b/c/d\n' | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1) FS $(NF)}'
/a
a/b
b/c
c/d
```

Answer (score 4):

You can cut using following ,
-d:  delimiter ,-f for fields
\t used for tab separated fields

```
cut -d$'\t' -f 1-3,7-
```

Answer (score 2):

To use AWK to cut off the first and last fields:

```
awk '{$1 = ""; $NF = ""; print}' inputfile
```

Unfortunately, that leaves the field separators, so

```
aaa bbb ccc
```

becomes

```
[space]bbb[space]
```

To do this using kurumi's answer which won't leave extra spaces, but in a way that's specific to your requirements:

```
awk '{delim = ""; for (i=2;i<=NF-1;i++) {printf delim "%s", $i; delim = OFS}; printf "\n"}' inputfile
```

This also fixes a couple of problems in that answer.

To generalize that:

```
awk -v skipstart=1 -v skipend=1 '{delim = ""; for (i=skipstart+1;i<=NF-skipend;i++) {printf delim "%s", $i; delim = OFS}; printf "\n"}' inputfile
```

Then you can change the number of fields to skip at the beginning or end by changing the variable assignments at the beginning of the command.

Comment: I am trying to cut the output from git branch-v, some lines have an extra * so I need to cut COLUMNS like OP asked, not fields, awk only works if you want to cut fields, different question ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash for that:

```
while read -a cols; do echo ${cols[@]:0:1} ${cols[@]:1,-1}; done < file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use awk, for example, cut off 1st,2nd and last 3 columns

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF-3;i++} print $i}' file
```

if you have a programing language such as Ruby (1.9+)

```
$ ruby -F"\t" -ane 'print $F[2..-3].join("\t")' file
```

Comment: your awk syntax seems to be off

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
echo a#b#c | awk -F"#" '{$1 = ""; $NF = ""; print}' OFS=""
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
cut -b COLUMN_N_BEGINS-COLUMN_N_UNTIL INPUT.TXT > OUTPUT.TXT
```

`-f` doesn't work if you have "tabs" in the text file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `How can I cut off the first n and the last n columns from a **tab** delimited file?` The question is about **TAB** columns and ranges up to and from to end. Your answer is about a continuous byte range

Comment: Unfortunately I only saw the title but not the content, does anyone know how can I delete my answers??